# LINQPad cannot connect to remote Sharepoint machine

Tags: linq, sharepoint-server

I have been working with the SP2010 OData interface to get some quick and dirty sheets as required by colleagues.

Now I need to use some additional methods (f.e.:GroubBy) and therefore need to use SPMetal.

However. Working on my Dev machine (Server 2008 R2, Sp2010 Server) I can connect to my local Sharepoint environment using the sp2010 drivers, but no remote machine seems to be reachable.
At this point it does not matter, if I choose to create the entities on the fly, or if I choose to use pregenerated entities.

The error I am getting (dynamic):

```
The Web application at http://sp2010machine/sitecollection can not be found
[...]
```

Afterwards LinqPad ist complaining it cannot locate the siteentities.cs, which I suspect is because of LP not being able to create it in the first place.

I hope you can help me on this, because I do not want to go around and install(and activate) Linqpad on our productive system.

Kind regards.